# Trouble displaying Check icon in FontAwesome React

Tags: reactjs, import, icons, font-awesome

I'm using Font Awesome and React. I'm hoping to display the check icon (https://fontawesome.com/icons/check) with the following code:

Creating a fontawesome library to consolidate imports:

```
import { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import { faCheck } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
library.add( faCheck );
```

I'm not getting errors at this point, suggesting that the check icon correct exported.

I'm then importing to another file using:

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

...

<FontAwesomeIcon icon="check" />
```

I'm not getting an error, but the icon also doesn't show up. This might be a naming issue.

Is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried like this and it worked.

```
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import {  faCheck } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";

/ and in the code where you want to display icon

<FontAwesomeIcon  icon={faCheck} />
```